# Mapping a Column with pojo in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a pojo class with the followings:

```
   class timed
    {
       int id;
       int minute;
       int time;
     }`
```

my sql query is

```
 select id as id, minute as minute from dummy;
```

my problem is the value for time is generated in the pojo class, i want to return that value also

Comment: what is "time is generated in pojo class" means ? ... in a method called `getTime()` you calculate the value ? ... then when you execute your select statement, it will return your pojo object, and a call on that getTime metho should return that calculated value, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer looks very simple .

- The dummy table should have column minute.
- The select should return the column minute.

Comment: I have a columns for both minute and id, the value for time is generated in pojo class, i want that value